# Finding a fundamental system of solutions of the homogeneous system

Tags: matrix

Hey guys im having problems with as the title says finding a fundamental system of solutions of the homogeneous system Vx = o

Based on :

Matrix

```
V = Partition[{1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 2, -3, 6, -3, 1, -1, -2, 6, -9, 7, 2, 1, -3, 10, -11, 1, -1, 3, 1, -4}, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica Matrix]

and Vector Columns:

```
b = Transpose[{{-11, 3, 14, 0, 14}}];
o = Transpose[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}];
```

[image: Mathematica Vector Column] and [image: Mathematica Vector Column]

I'm really confused as to the steps I should follow exactly to implement this. Any push in the right direction would be welcoming ! :)

Comment: Check documentation for `NullSpace`.

Answer (score 3):

Next time please provide Mathematica code to ease answering!

```
V = {{1, -2, 3, -4, 5}, {2, -3, 6, -3, 1}, {-1, -2, 6, -9, 7}, {2,1, -3, 10, -11}, {1, -1, 3, 1, -4}}

Solve[V.{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5} == 0, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]
(*{{x3 -> -((19 x1)/24) + (53 x2)/72, x4 -> -((9 x1)/8) + (5 x2)/8,x5 -> -((5 x1)/8) + (11 x2)/24}}*)
```

that's it!

Obviously V has reduced rank:

```
MatrixRank[V]
(*3*)
```